# Short-declaration operator shadows global variable

Tags: variables, go, assign

There is `oneFunction` that returns 2 values of types `int` and `error`.
I want to assign the first value to already existing variable and assign second value to a new variable.

---

If I use short declaration operator `:=`, there will be created 2 new variables `x` and `err`.

```
var x int
x, err := oneFunction()
```

---

To get rid of creating new `x` variable I must not use `:=` operator and declare `err` before calling `oneFunction`

```
    var x int
    var err error
    glob, err = oneFunction()
```

---

I'd like to know if there is another way to set first value to global variable instead of creating a new one?

Comment: There is nothing like Java's `this` in Go. What you did is the simplest, cleanest way to do what you wanted to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

No. Your example that declares `var err error` is the idiomatic way to do what you want.